# Boost::visitor same data types several times

Tags: c++, boost

I try to implement a data structure from a protocol. To make sure the payload type fits the contained data I have a visitor function to get the type. In all other data structures there are differen types used in the variant, expect here in the payload.

```
enum class PayloadType : uint8_t {
    Unsecured = 0,
    Signed = 1,
    Encrypted = 2,
    Signed_External = 3,
    Signed_And_Encrypted = 4
};

typedef ByteBuffer Unsecured;
typedef ByteBuffer Signed;
typedef ByteBuffer Encrypted;
typedef ByteBuffer SignedExternal;
typedef ByteBuffer SignedAndEncrypted;
typedef boost::variant<Unsecured, Signed, Encrypted, SignedExternal, SignedAndEncrypted> Payload;
```

Now the problem is, that every type in the visitor is the same (for example Signed is ab ByteBuffer like Encrypted is a ByteBuffer).

```
PayloadType get_type(const Payload& payload) {
struct PayloadVisitor : public boost::static_visitor <> {
  void operator()(const Unsecured& unsecured){
      mtype = PayloadType::Unsecured;
  }
  void operator()(const Signed& sign){
      mtype = PayloadType::Signed;
  }
  void operator()(const Encrypted& encrypted){
      mtype = PayloadType::Encrypted;
  }
  void operator()(const SignedExternal& external){
      mtype = PayloadType::Signed_External;
  }
  void operator()(const SignedAndEncrypted& sign){
      mtype = PayloadType::Signed_And_Encrypted;
  }
  PayloadType mtype;
};

PayloadVisitor visit;
boost::apply_visitor(visit, payload);
return visit.mtype;
}
```

Is there any way to make the different types distinguishable from each other?

I found that it works, if i put them into structs like:

```
struct SignedExternal {
    ByteBuffer buf;
}
struct Signed {
    ByteBuffer buf;
}
and so on..
```

But then its quite long-winded to work with the data types.
Maybe there is an easy way to achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you try to use `typedef` for something that it isn't: It does *not* declare a new type. (I think that might have changed for c++11, since that allows typedef'ed templates). If someone can find the reference in the standards, I'd be grateful, but for now, from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef):

> The typedef-names are aliases for existing types, and are not declarations of new types.

You simply don't get a new type by doing a typedef. Maybe inheritance might help you, giving you "real" new types, but I don't know whether that is a good idea in your overall application. It probably is -- your problem matches the idea of polymorphism just soooo nicely.

Generally, c++ is statically typed, so the idea of using the type of an object as part of the information might not be the best. Generally, you might just want your buffer class to have a field "type" that refers to your `enum` and act based on that field's value. But that's just poor man's inheritance. If you want to have poor C man's inheritance, do the same, but save a function pointer that "does the right thing" along with your buffer.

Comment: Yea i know that using the type as the information is no good way. But if I put a type field into my ByteBuffer Class, i have to make sure that no one sets the wrong type. Because the whole behavior of the deserialization is based on the type, read from my byte stream. I think i will use `struct Signed : ByteBuffer {}` to create a new type. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a strong typedef

```
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(SignedExternal, ByteBuffer);
```

There's two of them, one in Bosot Utility and one in Boost Serialization as I remember.

One of the two has more features (like lifting some operators, like comparison/equality as I remember).